# What was the exact time of announcement of Indian independence?

Tags: india, british-empire, independence

Unanimously, India achieved its independence on 15th August 1947. Of course, to say the exact time would be, a bit difficult. However, what time did they begin to address the nation to announce its independence?

What was the time of its announcement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the history archives of the [UK Parliament](http://www.parliament.uk/business/publications/parliamentary-archives/archives-highlights/indian-independence/), India became a "dominion" within the British commonwealth at midnight on 15th August 1947. At this time, India's new ministers and members of the constituent assembly took an oath to serve the new country, and the new office of the Governor General was created. (Wikipedia says without citation that the exact time was 12:02 am of 15th August, but I have not seen this time being mentioned anywhere else).

Comment: user571376 - I would be happy if we get an answer from the British history bureau of record keeping. Redistributing an online information again in internet isn't of no growth. We need to bring the information which are still only inform of books. However, I appreciate your answer and contribution.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://www.parliament.uk/business/publications/parliamentary-archives/archives-highlights/indian-independence/

Comment: user571376 - I appreciate your effort. Your 1st answer was more useful. Thank you so much!

Comment: The existing listed url is now invalid. The info can now be found on [this URL](http://www.parliament.uk/business/publications/parliamentary-archives/explore-guides-to-documentary-archive-/archives-highlights/indian-independence/) on website of British Parliament

Answer (score 2):

Here is one source from a fictional account confirming midnight of August 15th, 1947 (Bombay local time), [Salman Rushdie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salman_rushdie)'s *Midnight Children*:

> I was born in the city of Bombay ... once upon a time. No, that won't
>   do, there's no getting away from the date: I was born in Doctor
>   Narlikar's Nursing Home on August 15th, 1947. And the time? The time
>   matters, too. Well then: at night. No, it's important to be more ...
>   On the stroke of midnight, as a matter of fact. Clock-hands joined
>   palms in respectful greeting as I came. Oh, spell it out, spell it
>   out: at the precise instant of India's arrival at independence I
>   tumbled forth into the world.

Comment: And of course you could add: [Freedom at Midnight](http://www.amazon.in/Freedom-at-Midnight-Dominique-Lapierre/dp/8125931864).

Comment: I was about to suggest that when I stumbled on this question ;).

Answer (score 1):

India get the Independence on 15th August 1947 at 12:17 am the perfect time when the India get the Independence

Comment: This would be a better answer if it included more references and fewer opinions.

Comment: Down to the minute.